# How do I write automated tests?

Tags: testing

I saw that Drupal 7 includes some kind of testing framework (I haven't tried it out yet since my existing sites are still in Drupal 6 and likely won't migrate any time soon). How can you write automated testing for a Drupal 6 site, is there a module for this? How much can actually be tested automatically rather than requiring manual testing?

Comment: This topic is already well covered in the Drupal documentation (at http://drupal.org/simpletest). IMHO, to properly answer this kind of question in the Drupal community spirit one would either point to the existing documentation or write a long response that should actually be contributed as documentation on drupal.org and not on stackexchange.com

Comment: This is really broad: similar to "how do I build X site in Drupal?"

Comment: While broad, I think this is an important question, especially for new Drupalers. It also will provide a place for more discussion which will help all Drupalers as this site goes public. I also disagree that it's the same as "how do I build X". This is not as open ended. There are clear steps to be followed for all sites, making this a very relevant topic to every Drupal site out there.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

http://drupal.org/project/simpletest - it provides essentially the same testing API as the core D7 module and you still have to write the tests yourself. There is also http://drupal.org/project/simpletest_automator that apparently will help you 'record' your actions on a site into a SimpleTest for you.

Additional helpful links:

- http://drupal.org/project/selenium
- http://drupal.org/simpletest

Answer (score 9):

For *site* testing you may not find Simpletest the best solution. It's designed to test code, rather than the behavior of a site. You may be interested in more big-picture testing tools like [Selenium](http://drupal.org/project/selenium), as Dave Reid mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

A number of contributed modules for Drupal 6 includes simpletests. If you need inspiration take a look at the [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module for instance.