# How can I debug an email function?

Tags: 7, emails

I'm using flag_friend module and want to customize the email that is sent after a friend request is made.

What's the best way developing code for email functions like this where you can't just reload the page to see your changes?

I would have to go back, remove the friend request and create a new request to trigger the next email, then wait for the email to arrive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write an automated test with SimpleTest.

Takes quite a bit of initial effort but once you have it, it is a matter of a few seconds to re-run your test.

Simpletest also automatically intercepts sent mails and you can then get them directly in the test with `$this->drupalGetMails()`.

See for example [How do I write automated tests for a Drupal site?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154/how-do-i-write-automated-tests-for-a-drupal-site)